# how to handle "cancel all downloads" window of Firefox by selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

when the firefox is downloading a file, but I want to cancel it though selenium, so I try to close, and then it will pop up a window "cancel all downloads", I dont know how to handle it .

```
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

browser.close()
obj = browser.switch_to.alert
obj.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these arguments to disable any download messages:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
```